# Can't import django

Tags: django, windows-8.1, pip

I installed python 2.7 and then django via pip.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install Django
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 6.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting Django
  Downloading Django-1.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB)
    100% |################################| 6.2MB 79kB/s
Installing collected packages: Django

Successfully installed Django-1.8

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Now nothing is possible when I try to import django.

```
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
>>>
```

What can be done about it? I tried reinstalling pip and then suddenly nothing is possible again.

```
C:\Users\cleanup\Downloads>python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1MB)
    100% |################################| 1.1MB 335kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 1.5.4
    Uninstalling pip-1.5.4:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-1.5.4
Successfully installed pip-1.5.6

C:\Users\cleanup\Downloads>pip list
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\cleanup\Downloads>python pip list
python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\cleanup\Downloads>
```

Comment: What do you see when you `pip list`?

Comment: I think I must reinstall. Nothing is possible. I can't even use pip. I installed django successfully from ad administrator prompt. I update the question with the results from my installation earlier.

Comment: It seems pip attached to different python interpreter from that one where you've tried to import django.

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pip` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that Python cannot find `pip.py`. Please make sure the directory of `pip` is on search path.

To make that happen, you should goto "Advanced System Properties" > "Environment Variables" and add `%PYTHONHOME%\Scripts` to `PATH`. If you do not have `PYTHONHOME`, you should create the variable and set it to your Python home. In most cases, it is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python`.

Answer (score -2):

Since you have installed Python successfully, there is a useful document on the Django official website about [how to install Django on Windows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/windows/). I think there are some good resources you can refer to.

By the way, on Windows pip lives in `C:\[pythondir]\scipts`. Do not forget to put the pip path to your system PATH or just use a bat script:

```
@C:\[pythondir]/scripts\pip.exe %*
```